# Dynamic Menu in Android?

Tags: android

I need to show menu at the time of button Click.But I am not able to display the menu . My code is below. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code ??? Thanks in Advance !!!

Code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class DynamicMenu extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Context context;
Button btnMenu;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;


    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(context);

    btnMenu = new Button(context);
    btnMenu.setText("Show Menu");


    llay.addView(btnMenu);

    setContentView(llay);

    registerForContextMenu(btnMenu);

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    Menu m_menu = menu;
    m_menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Settings");
    m_menu.add(0, 2, 0, "About");
    m_menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Exit");
}

}
```

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What do you want to call ? `Menu` or `Context Menu` these are two diffrent things.

What you have coded causes a Context Menu to appear. (Long click the button to show the context menu) , heres a sample:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuDemo extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Context context;
Button btnMenu;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;


    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(context);

    btnMenu = new Button(context);
    btnMenu.setText("Show Menu");


    llay.addView(btnMenu);

    setContentView(llay);

    registerForContextMenu(btnMenu);

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {//Context Menu that appears when long clicked.
    Menu m_menu = menu;
    m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+1, 0, "Settings");
    m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+2, 0, "About");
    m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+3, 0, "Exit");
}

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Menu that appears when menu button is pressed on device
     Menu m_menu = menu;
     m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+3, 0, "Settings");
     m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+4, 0, "About");
     m_menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+5, 0, "Exit");
     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String msg="Selected from menu: ";
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case Menu.FIRST+3:
            Toast.makeText(this, msg+"Settings Menu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case Menu.FIRST+4:
            Toast.makeText(this, msg+"About Menu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case Menu.FIRST+5:
            Toast.makeText(this, msg+"Exit Menu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        String msg="Selected from context menu: ";
        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case Menu.FIRST+1:
            Toast.makeText(this, msg+"Settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case Menu.FIRST+2:
            Toast.makeText(this, msg+"About", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case Menu.FIRST+3:
            Toast.makeText(this, msg+"Exit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

This is not the best practiced and recommended code you can really make use of polymorphism here. But I hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

When i use the following code i can able to get the menu at the time of button               click

```
    registerForContextMenu(btnMenu);

    btnMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((DynamicMenu) context).openContextMenu(btnMenu);

        }
    });
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreateContextMenu` you are not calling the super class constructor. You can refer that from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Something like this `super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);`